# A fairy fantasy, possibly a trilogy - a woman lives in and used to be a tree, a house built with right-angles and iron

Tags: story-identification, fairy

I can’t remember many details, but I’d love to read it again. It starts off with a girl going to a small village. There was a tree, a woman lived in it or near it with her daughters. The tree used to be a woman also. Someone built a house with hard right angles and iron to keep fairies out. The story takes place in different time periods. I think the girl's fairy mother sent her to modern times to protect her or something.

Answer (score 3):

**Possibly Sheri S. Tepper's *[Beauty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauty_(Tepper_novel))* (1991)**

I don't recall all the details you mention, as it has been many years since I read the book. However, the protagonist, a girl called Beauty, has a fairy mother, and she travels between time periods, including the present. The book has versions of fairy tales like "Sleeping Beauty", "Snow White" and "Cinderella". There are several editions of this novel, so the cover below might not be recognizable to you.

[image]